# Can I avoid vertical texture stretching with this Unity shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm working on generating a dynamic world map, and using the Unity Texture Array to do so as it's texture base. However, the shader I currently have tiles fine on the x/z, but stretches badly on y. Is there any way to correct this so that it tiles on all three axis?

```
Shader "Custom/TerrainTexture" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Terrain Texture", 2DArray) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows
        #pragma target 3.5

        UNITY_DECLARE_TEX2DARRAY(_MainTex);

        struct Input {
            float4 color : COLOR;
            float3 worldPos;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            float2 uv = IN.worldPos.xz * 0.20;
            fixed4 c = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(_MainTex, float3(uv, 1));
            o.Albedo = c.rgb * _Color;
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?
Also how is it rendering on x y and z axes? Isn't it a 2D image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need triplanar mapping. The principle is that you project the texture on the XZ plane, just like you did, but then you also project it on the ZY and XY planes. Finally, you use the surface normal (usually squared multiple times) to blend the textures together (multiply and sum).

Here is how the blending function looks:

```
inline float3 TriplanarBlendFactor(half3 normal) {
    float3 bf = pow(abs(normal), 6);
    bf /= dot(bf, (float3)1);
    return bf;
}
```

Then just combine the texture samples like this:

```
fixed4 cx = tex2D(tex, tx) * blendFactor.x;
fixed4 cy = tex2D(tex, ty) * blendFactor.y;
fixed4 cz = tex2D(tex, tz) * blendFactor.z;
fixed4 finalColor = cx + cy + cz;
```

You can expose the power in the blending function as a shader property if you want control over the blending distance.

Comment: Brilliant. I couldn't quite understand the problem, but your answer both clarified it *and* answered the question. Add a bonus, you did so succinctly.